# jquery validation and ajax not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-validate

I have a script that validates and submits using jquery validate and ajax which is working on desktop, but not on mobile. I can't find the problem.

They are going into the click but not further,

Its about two form, which are almost exactly the same but some minor differences.
this is my javascript. 
`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#offerteSeperateForm #ck-button.submit").click(function() {
            $("#offerteSeperateForm").validate({
                ignore: ":hidden",
                rules: {
                    name:{
                        minlength:2,
                        required:true                        
                    },
                    telephone:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:10,
                        maxlength:10         
                    },
                    email:{
                        required:true,
                        email: true                  
                    },
                    personen:{
                        required:true                        
                    },
                    personen:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    day:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength:2,
                        max: 31,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    month:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength:2,
                        max: 12,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    year:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        min: <?php echo date('Y'); ?>
                    }
                },
               submitHandler: function (form) {




                    $.ajax({
                         var data = $('form#offerteSeperateForm').serialize();
                        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
                        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/processOfferteSeperate.php", 

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "POST",

                        //pass the data         
                        data: data,     

                        //Do not cache the page
                        cache: false,


                        //success
                        success: function (html) {     

                            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                            if (html==1) {                  
    alert('succes');
                            window.location = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/?p=146";

                            //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                            } else alert('Sorry, er ging iets mis. Wilt u het nogmaals proberen?');               
                        }       
                    });

            return false;
                }   
            });

        });



            $( "#offerteForm #ck-button.submit" ).click(function() {

            $("#offerteForm").validate({
                ignore: ":hidden",
                rules: {
                    name:{
                        minlength:2,
                        required:true                        
                    },
                    telephone:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:10,
                        maxlength:10         
                    },
                    email:{
                        required:true,
                        email: true                  
                    },
                    personen:{
                        required:true                        
                    },
                    personen:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    day:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength:2,
                        max: 31,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    month:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        maxlength:2,
                        max: 12,
                        min: 0
                    },
                    year:{
                        required:true,
                        number: true,
                        min: <?php echo date('Y'); ?>
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {

                    $.ajax({
                        var data = $('form#offerteForm').serialize();

                        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
                        url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/processOfferte.php", 

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "POST",

                        //pass the data         
                        data: data,     

                        //Do not cache the page
                        cache: false,


                        //success
                        success: function (html) {     
                               alert('succes');
                            //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                            if (html==1) {                  

                            window.location = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/?p=146";

                            //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                            } else alert('Sorry, er ging iets mis. Wilt u het nogmaals proberen?');               
                        }       
                    });
                    return false;

                }   
            });
        });
    });
```

`
these are the form tags

`<form action="" id="offerteForm" method="post">
<form action="" id="offerteSeperateForm" method="post">`

Comment: i think inside submithandler "return false;" is getting executed before ajax completes.

Comment: I added return false as a something I read on stackoverflow as someone elses solution so i thought i tried, but why is it working on desktop and not on mobile?

Comment: In general, you don't have to put the `$.validate` calls inside of `click` handlers.  They can be put at the top level, inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ //validate here });`.  Assuming your submit buttons are actually `<input type="submit">` it will just do the right thing.  I'm not sure that will solve your problem, but it won't hurt!  Beyond that, you need to make a simpler example and include all the relevant HTML

Comment: Show the relevant HTML.  And are you using jQuery Mobile or are you just talking about a mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole problem is caused by thinking that `.validate()` needs to be inside of a `click` handler.

The `.validate()` method is not for triggering a validation test and cannot be called multiple times on the same form.

Simply call the `.validate()` method *once* within your DOM ready event handler.  The `.validate()` method is for initializing the plugin.  The `click` event is captured (*as long as button contains a `type="submit"`*) and then validation is performed... automatically.

---

**EDIT**:

Based on the comment, there's still much confusion by the OP.

- In other words, with your code the plugin is NOT even initialized until the first click.
- In other other words, your first click only initializes the plugin... then it sits there and does nothing until you click a second time.  This behavior *could* be different in every browser since it depends on the timing of each event *(the click is both initializing the plugin and trying to submit the form at nearly the same instant)*.  So the way to make it consistent and predictable is to simply initialize the plugin within the DOM ready event handler and allow the plugin to capture the `click` event by itself... exactly as it was designed.

**The `.validate()` method is never supposed to be inside of a `click` handler.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // DOM ready event handler

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6he8a15n/**

---

It's not entirely clear whether you're having this issue with jQuery Mobile or simply on a mobile platform.  However, just in case for jQuery Mobile, the DOM ready event handler looks somewhat different...

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){ // DOM ready event handler for jQuery Mobile

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        ....
```

**Mobile DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6he8a15n/1/**

Comment: the submit buttons are indeed type=submit, but i need the click events due to other components on the page. The script for the two forms totaly works on desktop and tablet but not on mobile, which i think is strange.

Comment: @TiemenTuinstra, you are showing us nothing inside the `click` handler except for `.validate()`.  Since the `.validate()` method is **only used for initializing** the plugin, you should **never** have it inside of a `click` event handler.  When the plugin is properly initialized, you would not have the problems you describe.